# python "is" equivalency is confusing for some mutable objects

Tags: python, mutability, equivalence

this is the first time i'm asking a question; i apologise in advance for any mistakes i may make out of ignorance;

here's my question:
why do i get "False" for any equivalence of mutable objects using 'is' while they seem to point at the same memory location?

```
>>> 1 is 1
True
>>> "a" is "a"
True
>>> 'b' is 'b'
True
>>> () is ()
True
>>> [] is []
False
>>> {} is {}
False
```

````
>>> print(id({}), id({}))
(140262895310280, 140262895310280)
>>> print(id([]), id([]))
(140262895262032, 140262895262032)
>>> print(id(()), id(()))
(140262896386128, 140262896386128)```
````

Comment: The rule of thumb is never use `is` unless you're doing `is None` or `is not None`.

Comment: `is` checks for identity, not equivalency. Strings and integers are cached in some implementations, so two occurances of `"a"` can actually be the same object, while two lists `[]` are not the same object but two different, empty lists. Use `==` to check for equivalency.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#id20 for a note on this behavior.

Comment: thank you very much for your help guys!

Comment: Note that all the cases here where `is` returns true is implementation-dependent. There's no reason Python *must* cause any of those immutable literals to evaluate to the same object; it's a performance optimization that it *can*.